# From Memory Address to Source Line of Code

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

I'm using WinDBG and have the following stack trace:

```
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xa
KERNELBASE!TerminateProcess+0x2f
MSVCR90!_invoke_watson+0x11c [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\invarg.c @ 234]
MSVCR90!_invalid_parameter+0x70 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\invarg.c @ 115]
MSVCR90!fgetpos+0x33 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\fgetpos.c @ 45]
CleanPayload!DoSomething+0x22 [c:\users\brent.arias\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\samplecpplibrary\cleanpayload\cleanpayload.cpp @ 68]
CleanPayload!main+0x1c [c:\users\brent.arias\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\samplecpplibrary\cleanpayload\cleanpayload.cpp @ 115]
CleanPayload!__tmainCRTStartup+0x11a [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crtexe.c @ 586]
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

Clearly the debugger knows what line of code each stack frame points to, as it shows that number after the '@'.  I'm glad that I can hit crtl-l on the source pane and type in the line number, but why can't it do this for me?  Is there a way to click on the debug window and say "jump to this point in source" without me having to type it in myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can do this, just not from any window. It works from Call Stack window (Alt+6) -- double click on the frame that has mapped to the line of code and it will get you to the line in source file. It opens the file if it is not currently opened in WinDbg.

Comment: Note that this only works if you have the proper symbols for the library and the expected code present and WinDBG can find both. It will sometimes (depending on settings I think) pop up the source file and/or disassembly automatically.

Comment: Good point. You need symbols loaded and source files accessible for this to work. The Call Stack window has header buttons that serve as an additional information to display in the call stack, Source button makes it a bit easier to understand if you have symbols loaded.